# C vector указателей на структуру

Tags: c

Пушу в вектор указатель на структу. Хочу получить из вектора тот же самый указатель, а получаю совсем другой результат.

```
typedef struct
{
    void *pData;
    int elemSz;
    int size;

    int realMemSize; //real size of the allocated memory
} vector;

vector * createVector(int elSz, int size)
{
    vector * vec = malloc(sizeof(vector));

    vec->realMemSize=elSz * size;
    vec->size=0;
    vec->elemSz=elSz;
    vec->pData = malloc(vec->realMemSize);
    return vec;
}

void deleteVector(vector *vec)
{
    vec->realMemSize = 0;
    vec->size = 0;
    vec->elemSz = 0;
    free(vec->pData);
    vec->pData = NULL;
}

void vector_resize(vector *vec, int capacity)
{
    printf("Vector resize: %d to %d\n", capacity, vec->realMemSize);
    vec->pData = realloc(vec->pData, capacity);
    vec->realMemSize = capacity;
}

void push_back_vector(vector *vec, void *elem)
{
    if(vec->size == vec->realMemSize) {
        vector_resize(vec, vec->realMemSize * 2);
    }
    memcpy((vec->pData + vec->elemSz * vec->size++), elem, vec->elemSz);
}

void delete_from_vector(vector *vec,int position)
{
    if(0 <=position && position <= vec->size)
    {
        for(int i = position; i < vec->size;i++)
        {
            memcpy((vec->pData+i), (vec->pData+i+1), vec->elemSz);
        }
        vec->size--;
    }

}

void *vector_get(vector *vec, int position)
{
    if(0 <=position && position <= vec->size)
        return (vec->pData + vec->elemSz * position);
    return NULL;
}

typedef struct
{
    void *pData;
    int elemSz;
    int size;

    int realMemSize; //real size of the allocated memory
} vector;

vector * createVector(int elSz, int size)
{
    vector * vec = malloc(sizeof(vector));

    vec->realMemSize=elSz * size;
    vec->size=0;
    vec->elemSz=elSz;
    vec->pData = malloc(vec->realMemSize);
    return vec;
}

void deleteVector(vector *vec)
{
    vec->realMemSize = 0;
    vec->size = 0;
    vec->elemSz = 0;
    free(vec->pData);
    vec->pData = NULL;
}

void vector_resize(vector *vec, int capacity)
{
    printf("Vector resize: %d to %d\n", capacity, vec->realMemSize);
    vec->pData = realloc(vec->pData, capacity);
    vec->realMemSize = capacity;
}

void push_back_vector(vector *vec, void *elem)
{
    if(vec->size == vec->realMemSize) {
        vector_resize(vec, vec->realMemSize * 2);
    }
    memcpy((vec->pData + vec->elemSz * vec->size++), elem, vec->elemSz);
}

void delete_from_vector(vector *vec,int position)
{
    if(0 <=position && position <= vec->size)
    {
        for(int i = position; i < vec->size;i++)
        {
            memcpy((vec->pData+i), (vec->pData+i+1), vec->elemSz);
        }
        vec->size--;
    }

}

void *vector_get(vector *vec, int position)
{
    if(0 <=position && position <= vec->size)
        return (vec->pData + vec->elemSz * position);
    return NULL;
}typedef struct
{
    void *pData;
    int elemSz;
    int size;

    int realMemSize; //real size of the allocated memory
} vector;

vector * createVector(int elSz, int size)
{
    vector * vec = malloc(sizeof(vector));

    vec->realMemSize=elSz * size;
    vec->size=0;
    vec->elemSz=elSz;
    vec->pData = malloc(vec->realMemSize);
    return vec;
}

void deleteVector(vector *vec)
{
    vec->realMemSize = 0;
    vec->size = 0;
    vec->elemSz = 0;
    free(vec->pData);
    vec->pData = NULL;
}

void vector_resize(vector *vec, int capacity)
{
    printf("Vector resize: %d to %d\n", capacity, vec->realMemSize);
    vec->pData = realloc(vec->pData, capacity);
    vec->realMemSize = capacity;
}

void push_back_vector(vector *vec, void *elem)
{
    if(vec->size == vec->realMemSize) {
        vector_resize(vec, vec->realMemSize * 2);
    }
    memcpy((vec->pData + vec->elemSz * vec->size++), elem, vec->elemSz);
}

void delete_from_vector(vector *vec,int position)
{
    if(0 <=position && position <= vec->size)
    {
        for(int i = position; i < vec->size;i++)
        {
            memcpy((vec->pData+i), (vec->pData+i+1), vec->elemSz);
        }
        vec->size--;
    }

}

void *vector_get(vector *vec, int position)
{
    if(0 <=position && position <= vec->size)
        return (vec->pData + vec->elemSz * position);
    return NULL;
}

typedef struct
{
    variable * left_hand_side;
    alg_expression * right_hand_side;
    bool is_solution;
} math_equality;

int main(){
 vector * equalities_ptr_vec = createVector(sizeof(math_equality*), VECTOR_INIT_CAPACITY);

    math_equality * eq = createEquality(10,10);
    push_back_vector(equalities_ptr_vec, eq);
    math_equality *ret_eq = vector_get(equalities_ptr_vec,0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Похоже дважды скопировал код в сообщение...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В коде содержатся ошибки, основанных на путанице с размерностями. Поле `realMemSize` содержит размер выделенной памяти *в байтах*. Поле `size` содержит текущий размер вектора *в элементах*. Поэтому сравнивать друг с другом эти поля ни в коем случае нельзя - это бессмысленно.

А у вас

```
void push_back_vector(vector *vec, void *elem)
{
    if(vec->size == vec->realMemSize) {           // <---- Что это???
        vector_resize(vec, vec->realMemSize * 2);
    }
    memcpy((vec->pData + vec->elemSz * vec->size++), elem, vec->elemSz);
}
```

Также непонятно, почему функция `createVector` выделяет память и для самого вектора, и для хранящихся в нем данных, а вроде бы симметричная ей функция `deleteVector` освобождает только данные, но не сам вектор.

Функция `createVector` получает начальную емкость вектора *в элементах*, а функция `vector_resize` получает новую емкость *в байтах* - опять какая-то мешанина размерностей.

---

> Хочу получить из вектора тот же самый указатель, а получаю совсем другой результат.

Ваша функция `vector_get` возвращает *указатель на элемент вектора*. Он вам и не должна возвращать те данные, которые вы туда поместили. Она вам возвращает *указатель* на те данные которые вы туда поместили.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> push_back_vector(equalities_ptr_vec, eq);
> ```

Если это вектор указателей (судя по размеру), то должно быть:

```
push_back_vector(equalities_ptr_vec, &eq);
```

`vector_get` аналогично возвращает указатель на указатель, т.е. должно быть:

```
math_equality **ret_eq = vector_get(equalities_ptr_vec,0);
```

Если же это вектор структур, то должно быть:

```
vector * equalities_ptr_vec = 
      createVector(sizeof(math_equality), VECTOR_INIT_CAPACITY);
```

Указатель будут разные, но указывать они будут на одинаковые данные.

#### Другие замечания:

- Стоит придерживаться одинокого стиля написания имён функций (camelCase или подчёркивания).
- Здесь скорей всего должно быть строго меньше во втором случае:

  > ```
  > if(0 <=position && position <= vec->size)
  > ```